# How to Open a Browser and connect to a website then parse that website using jsoup in java?

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup

I have a project which needs a little bit of web-scraping. The main requirement is to let the user enter his data on a java application. Then the application will connect to a data entry website then it will automatically inputs the data entered by the user to that website. I haven't started to code it since I don't know where to start. I already conducted some research about this and it points me to jsoup and desktop api(jsoup for webscraping and desktop api for opening a browser). Hope to receive a reply from the Java experts here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

JSoup will certainly do the scraping for you. However you need to handle HTTP (GETs/POSTs etc.) and for that I would recommend [Apache Http Components](http://hc.apache.org/).

I'm not sure you want to open a browser. Rather I would expect you to ask the user for input (perhaps via a Swing UI, or a browser-based UI) and then talk directly to the website using HTTP. I don't think you'd need to open a browser to the destination website. If you do, then check out [Watij](http://watij.com/), which allows you to drive a browser directly from Java.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for this. I will try to test what you've shared to me.